# Bounding box coordinates via video object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object, tracking, bounding-box

Is it possible to get the coordinates of the detected object through video object detection?  I used OpenCV to change video to images and LabelImg to put the bounding box to them. For the output, I want to be able to read (for a video file) the coordinates of the bounding box so I could get the centre of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Object Detection works on per image or per frame basis.

The basic object detection model takes image as input and gives back the detected bounding boxes.

Now, what you need to do is, once your model is trained, read a video, frame by frame, or by skippng 'n' frames, pass the frame or image to the object detector and get the coordinates from it and show it into the output video frame.

That is how object detection works for a video.

Please refer to below links for references : 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
https://www.edureka.co/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-tutorial/